# jQuery UI Slider lags in chrome in the presence of an embedded flash object

Tags: flash, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, lag, jquery-slider

I am using the [LayerSlider](http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-the-parallax-effect-slider/full_screen_preview/922100) jQuery UI Plugin which is a simple image slider. The slider seems to work fine in all browsers when tested alone. But i have a menu bar which is an embedded swf flash object. If i use the jQuery Slider below the swf menu, the slider seems to malfunction in chrome and safari. It works fine in FF on all occasions.

This is what i mean by malfunctioning. Open this link in FF and Chrome. 
http://click-printit.co.uk/Test/

In FF, the slides are smooth and it is in sync with the little progress bar in the bottom. In Chrome it is totally out of sync.

This is the version without the flash menu on the top. 
http://click-printit.co.uk/Test/simple_slider.html

This seems to work good in all browsers.

If i insert these 4 lines of code in the latter link, the slider doesnt seem to work in Chrome.

```
<div>
            <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="Menu.swf" width="953" height="38">
              <param name="quality" value="high" />
              <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
              <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
            </object>
    </div>
```

Any thoughts on why the slider fails only when there is a flash object present alongside ? And only in Chrome and Safari ?

Answer (score 3):

following are params i have used in my project

```
                <param name="play" value="true" />
                <param name="loop" value="true" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="true" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                 <param name="base" value=" Flash/ShefBio/" />
```

but i think u should not use
param value="transparent" 
param swfversion value="6.0.65.0" 
my code works for ie,chrome but its not fully working with firefox it fact it is not obeying external css....